# Ksoap2 Trouble consuming Webservices on Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-intent, android-activity, ksoap2

I created a webServices in .net but  there is a trouble when I am consuming it from my Android app. I noticed that the webservice is not getting the parameters I send from Android. however, I consumed it from the .net app and it works ok.

*Note: with another webservice (webservicex/globalweather .asmx) my Android app works perfectly.*

I put some spaces in the string URL variable because I can't publish more than 2 links

```
public class cargaDatosWS {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.esmerlinp.somee.com/getAccess";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getAccess";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.esmerlinp.somee.com";
    private static final String URL = "http ://www. esmerlinp.somee .com/Registro.asmx";

    public String getAcess(String Email,String Pwd){
        String res=null;
        SoapObject rpc;
        rpc = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        rpc.addProperty("email", Email);
        rpc.addProperty("password", Pwd);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.bodyOut = rpc;
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport= null;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            res = envelope.getResponse().toString();

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            res=e.getMessage();
        }

        return res;

    }

}
```

Comment: please no, no, no ... not yet another NOMTE .... http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: I am not having troubles with asycnTask.

Comment: yeah ... rather lack of the asynctask ... [for FSM sake!](http://bit.ly/Vn6wfB)

Comment: I god the async task declaration in another Activity and it call the method I published here. my  real problem is the my webservices is not receiving the parameters I send.     rpc.addProperty("email", Email);
    rpc.addProperty("password", Pwd)

Comment: ok then name the problem ... are you getting any exception ? no? then only magic orb can help you ... yes? then why it is not in the question? ...

Comment: @EsmerlinPaniagua Please include the error message that you see when you try to consume from your web service.

Comment: Not, am not getting any exception. I am just receiving null from webservices, because it never get the parameter I send.

Comment: Ok, when you say "receiving null" it may help to show an example of what that looks like in your application. For example, copy paste the output, or show a stacktrace of the null pointer exception.

Comment: is your .NET framework version over4.5?